# pytest collects and passes tests locally, but 'collected 0 items' in GitHub Actions workflow (exit code 5)

Tags: pytest, github-actions, github-actions-workflows

I'm new to GitHub Actions workflows and encountering an issue with [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/). Locally, my tests are successfully collected and pass without any problems. However, when running the same tests in a GitHub Actions workflow, pytest fails to recognize any tests and displays the error "collected 0 items" with exit code 5.

I have followed the pytest naming conventions by naming the test file, the test class, and the test function appropriately:

File name: test_example.py

Class name: TestExample

Function name: test_example

For running the test, I use the following command:

`pytest --doctest-modules --durations=10 --pyargs <package name>`

To provide more context, I've created a simple repository where you can find the code: [github](https://github.com/ariel-research/example/tree/main)

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. I'm happy to provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the issue was resolved by removing the usage of `pyargs` from the pytest command..